# Posting GPL code in an answer

Tags: discussion, licensing

I would like to answer a question about modifying code to handle an API change in a Linux kernel release. I feel that the best way to do this is to annotate an example from an actual kernel module that has gone through the change. If I wrote an example from scratch to demonstrate it, huge chunks of it would end up being nearly identical to my reference simply because there aren't too many ways to do it differently while following kernel conventions and because I'm not very familiar with the "old" way of doing it outside what I've learned from reading the diffs.

The problem is that I am pretty sure the GPL license on the kernel would conflict with the CC BY-SA license over here.

Is this correct? Is there a good way to work around it?

Comment: I think you can add references (links) to the source code hosted on the another server released with GPL, the link is CC BY-SA, while the code on the server of your choosing is GPL. Or maybe Screenshots!?

Comment: [GPL doesn't affect Fair Use](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLFairUse), and Jeff Atwood's opinion is that [if it isn't suitable for Fair Use it probably shouldn't be posted here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25956/what-is-up-with-the-source-code-license-on-stack-overflow/25957#25957), which might help; but someone else points out that [this might make *using* the example difficult](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12537).

Comment: From a practical point of view, I'm sure no one would sue you for posting a snippet to answer a question.

Comment: Does the question *also* include GPL code?

Comment: Quoting a tiny part of a work (several words, a line of code) cannot be copyright infringement, because such a small extract is never protected by copyright. Quoting more could be regarded as fair use, but one can never be sure about that. http://janefriedman.com/2013/07/15/the-fair-use-doctrine/

Comment: There is a related question *Can I safely incorporate a code-fragment from SO into my own work?*.  SO's requirement that all code posted should be licensed with the CC BY-SA license superficially suggests you can, but this doesn't protect you from the case where an answerer posts code that they don't have permission to release under CC BY-SA themselves.  You'll still be on the hook with the original rights-holder, and worse, you have no way of knowing until you get a writ.

Comment: Actually CC BY-SA conflicts with GPL and once a developer didn't tell anyone they had used SO code and later I had to go find the SO poster and get him to dual license as GPL, which he was nice about doing. Also signed a contributor agreement iirc.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**In short**: No, you cannot post GPL code here.

The FSF [considers the CC-BY-SA to be incompatible with the GPL](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/license-list.html#ccbysa) (the dashed yellow line along the left of the page indicates this, as shown in the key at the top of the page).  While this is not the same as an actual court case establishing the fact, it's the next best thing.

Stack Exchange's [terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) require you to license *all* contributions under the CC-BY-SA; you are not allowed to pick and choose (i.e. "this code is GPL, but the rest of my answer is CC-BY-SA").

Posting *small* amounts of example code may be legal under fair use, depending on the four factors.  However, this is a complicated issue which [programmers often get wrong](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/12196/153279) (edit: particularly by *upvoting things linked in meta posts without reading the comments*).  Fair use is always evaluated on a case-by-case basis, which means *the only way to be absolutely sure you're in the clear is to get sued and win*.  You probably don't want to do that.

Comment: When I grant SE, Inc. and the readers a CC-BY-SA license to my answer, it comes with an interesting warranty disclaimer.

Comment: A narrow but notable exception, not the case the OP seems to have in mind, is to post ones own code with a GPL license.  In such case the Reader would be free to use the code under either license, as the author is free under copyright law to provide [dual licensing](http://producingoss.com/en/dual-licensing.html).

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much what I was thinking too. I think it would be fair use because I'm breaking it up and commenting on it, but that doesn't mean someone wouldn't copy and paste it all into their own project. That would be a violation on their end, not ours, but to play it safe (especially since none of us are SO's lawyers) I'll just hold off on answering it.

Comment: If it is your own code you can dual license.

Comment: Who would sue me? The FSF, or the original author? Seriously?

Comment: @PeterSchneider: The copyright holder.  That might or might not be the author.  The FSF retains copyright in all GNU code, for example.

Comment: So somebody who GPLed their code sues me because I posted some of it on SO (with the copyright)? That seems remote to me -- excessively remote: "The fundamental focus of the licenses [...] is the preservation of users’ rights to run programs for any purpose, to copy, modify and share without restriction. ".(http://www.softwarefreedom.org/resources/2014/SFLC-Guide_to_GPL_Compliance_2d_ed.html#who-has-compliance-obligations). No commercial damage done either. Worst case is a letter and a post delete. But I cannot see why anybody would write that letter. **Let's be less paranoid.**

Comment: I *do* understand that SO may balk at GPLed code because the GPL restricts the rights they reserve in their terms of use (e.g. "create derivative works" not necessrily GPLed itself). Would they? Is there precedence that SO took down posts with GPLed code?

Comment: @Peter: If I'm preparing some CC-BY-SA material such as a Wikipedia article, I can directly embed Stack Overflow material (with attribution) into my product, and rework it to fit my needs.  I can then *sell* that article to others (perhaps as a physical document as part of a larger collection or something).  If I suddenly discover your answer is violating copyright laws and I have to pay my expensive lawyer lots of money to deal with it, you can imagine I'll be just a little annoyed.  So please don't violate others' copyrights.

Comment: And yes, [they really are reselling Wikipedia articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WP:1.0).

Comment: @Kevin since I included the original copyright (i,e., the GPL) in my post, you should perhaps have thought twice before you sold it. Btw, selling GPLed material per se is no violation (e.g. GNU/Linux distros) as long as the source code/text is made freely available and the (GPL) copyright is shown. You just can't *appropriate* that stuff and derivatives, i.e. make it your own and remove it from the public. Thats what all the lawsuits about e.g. embedded devices running GPLed SW are about. Publishing the derivative (or paying a share!) usually settles the case.

Comment: Oh, just to make clear: If you want to follow the law by the letter, then no, do not post GPL code here. My objections are not of a legal nature but of a practical nature, along the line of *Nullo actore, nullus iudex*. If you always follow the law to the letter this will be one of your lesser problems ;-).

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Selling GPLed code may not be a violation, but combining GPL and CC-BY-SA material is, and selling it increases the likelihood of getting sued and losing.