# How do we handle licensed code that was edited into a post?

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51147088/1), a user linked to code from an external resource, namely [Thomas Bluemel's texdiffcore](https://github.com/thezaza101/textdiffcore/blob/master/src/TextDiffEngines/Diff/Diff.cs). `texdiffcore` is apparently GPL licensed. Another user then [included the code from the external resource](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51147088/2), which breaks the GPL (see [Questions about GPL’d code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361220/questions-about-gpl-d-code?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

I've rolled the edit back (although I left the original author's example code). `texdiffcore` is still in the [post's history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51147088/2), though, and therefore still available under CC-BY-SA, which it shouldn't be. Which begs the question:

How should we handle licensed code, that wasn't posted by the original author of the licensed work or by the original questioner?

Comment: Is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285864/question-on-plagiarized-licensed-code/285871#285871) related?

Comment: Flag it for mod attention.

Comment: @Chris The answer linked in the first comment suggests you should not flag it for mod attention.

Comment: @BartoszKP indeed. I did not read it. However, generally speaking (not just for this specific scenario) for problematic posts/comments, I tend to suggest: *when in doubt, ask mods*. That said, it seems we already have an answer to this question.

Comment: Since when do we enforce third parties' copyrights here? The authorship of the code was clearly shown, so there was no plagiarism, which is all that the [referencing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) require. In the absence of a DMCA request we wouldn't remove an answer that, say, quoted several paragraphs from a book with attribution, so why should we treat this differently? Tell me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me like you're applying a stricter standard *because* the code is GPL-licensed than you would if it had no license at all, which doesn't make sense to do.